# Designed my way into a dynamic_cast how should I proceed?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

I am reading [Simple Event Handling](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/simple-event-handling-r2141).  The author uses a simple struct for his events, but suggests:

> A possible improvement here is to pass around a pointer to an Event
>   class instead of a structure. The Event class could then contain any
>   amount of information, and derived classes could be created for
>   different types of events. I choose a simpler option, mainly because
>   the scope of our project didn't require such a complex solution.

I implemented this as:

```
class Event
{
public:
typedef unsigned long   EventType;

explicit    Event(EventType type);
EventType   getType() const;

private:
EventType   mType;
};

class EventStr : public Event
{
public:
typedef unsigned long   EventType;

EventStr(EventType type, std::string str);
std::string getString() const;

private:
std::string mString;
};

void EventDispatcher::sendEvent(const Event& event);

main()
{
   Event e = EventStr(0x496bf752, "derived data");
   SendEvent(e);
}
```

My thought was derived types could have their own unique data (in this example a string).  However, I see this would require the use of dynamic_cast to access EventStr::getString when the event was being handled.  On the flip-side I didn't use virtual functions, because I wanted the base class to be barebones and have the specific details in the derived class.

My understanding is dynamic_casts are typical of a poor design.  That was my red flag.  Is it possible to have a barebones base class and then add additional details to the derived class while still being able to pass the derived type around as a reference to the base class?  If not what was the author suggesting?

Comment: I guess as you are already assigning your own unique EventType "type IDs" you can already figure out the exact type of your Event reference. When you know the exact type, you can simply use static_cast<> to access the details of the specialized event type. If you would retreat from the use of your own type system as you do with your EventType, you could use C++ built-in RTTI via the means of typeid and dynamic_cast but as you said, it's still a heavyweight.

Answer (score 1):

If you have different event types, having a base event class and derived classes for the variant events is how object orientation is supposed to be used. Use function members defining pure virtuals for the different ways events react to their environment. The idea is precisely that so you can pass around objects as if they are of the base class.

You should look at a good C++ tutorial (yes, there are many "object oriented programming" tutorials/texts around, but the OOP languages are *very* different, so not all are of help). One I've seen is the one at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/book), perhaps the [wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming). I'd bet Stroustrup's current [The C++ Programming Language](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) is very thorough and clear (judging from a much earlier edtion I own).

Comment: The Event class only has an EventType.  The derived types expand on this by adding a member variable and a getter.

There is a common base, but there isn't a common interface to implement.  Maybe this is my design problem.